# The following error is displayed every time I host my eclipse web app on xampp server

Tags: firebase, jsp

In the console log, the following error is displayed:

> It looks like you are using a development build of the firebase JS SDK. When deploying firebase apps to production. it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use. For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc)

I just added the attached code to my jsp page to establish firebase web app connectivity.

```
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase.js"></script>

        <script>
          // Initialize Firebase
          var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyC3rYNa3PqoQBDhb6DXW0pSHqQ2OaqTXJw",
            authDomain: "eventbot-1547110186249.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://eventbot-1547110186249.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "eventbot-1547110186249",
            storageBucket: "eventbot-1547110186249.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "694520066277"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including Firebase with:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

This includes all Firebase SDKs for all products, including the Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, Cloud Messaging, Authentication, Cloud Storage, and more. It's 770Kb (!) of JavaScript in total.

It is very unlikely that you're using all of these products in your page. So the warning is there to indicate that it's better to only include the more granular SDKs for the products you use.

For example, if you only use Firebase Cloud Messaging, you could use this import:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

This reduces the amount of code you load to 67 Kb (over 90% less), which will be appreciated by your users.

For more on this, see the documentation on [adding Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app), which also contains a list of the SDKs and how to include them.